# python libXML2 remove Item

Tags: python, libxml2, removechild

I am using libxml2 under python. Unfortunatly the python version of this library is really badly documented and i founded just few example on the web from there i could understand some of the method.

I managed the add a soon te a XML Node. Since this element should replace an existing one I would like to remove the previos one before but i could not find which is the method to remove a child.

Does anyone know what is the method name? does anyone have a decent documentation about this library?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `unlinkNode()` method to remove a given node.  In general, most of the methods that apply to nodes are documented, try:

```
pydoc libxml2.xmlNode
```

For `unlinkNode`, the documentation says:

```
unlinkNode(self)
    Unlink a node from it's current context, the node is not
    freed
```

For example, given this input:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">This is a test.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can parse the file like this:

```
>>> import libxml2
>>> doc = libxml2.parseFile('input.html')
```

Locate the `<div>` node like this:

```
>>> node = doc.xpathEval('//*[@id="content"])[0]
```

And remove it like this:

```
>>> node.unlinkNode()
```

And now if you print out the document, you get this:

```
>>> print doc
<head>            
    <title>Document Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pydoc command rocks. i did not know about! :)

Comment: perfect. sorry for bothering but i am new to this library. do you know why when i add some items it ads all of them on the same line? do you know how to get a pretty representation out? thanks a lot fot he help u already gave me! :)

Comment: If you're not forced to work with this library for some reason I would really recommend moving to lxml, which is a lot more pythonic and has much better documentation.

Comment: The `saveFormatFile` method will save a pretty-printed version of the document to the named file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you are using the `lxml` bindings for libXML2? They're documented reasonably well IMO at http://lxml.de/.

It mentions that elements are lists. So you can use the `remove` list function to remove a node.

```
import lxml
root = lxml.etree.Element("root")
child2 = lxml.etree.SubElement(root, "child2")
child3 = lxml.etree.SubElement(root, "child3")
print lxml.etree.tostring(root)
#    "<root><child2/><child3/></root>"
root.remove( child2 )
print lxml.etree.tostring(root)
#    "<root><child3/></root>"
```

Comment: I think he's talking about this: http://xmlsoft.org/python.html

Comment: well... no realy i am actually using directly libxml2 "import libxml2"

Comment: exaclty this one... it's very fast but documentation really pour. i found the source here but hard to get info out: http://www.mit.edu/activities/anime/arch/i386_rhel4/pkg/vlc-0.8.6d/contrib/lib/python2.3/site-packages/libxml2.py

Comment: @something (and Stefano) :Ah, that page even recommends that "python purists may prefer lxml". If you're familiar with libXML2 as a C library (with its equally tricky docs) then the python bindings will probably make sense as I believe they're a pretty direct conversion. However I'd consider using lxml instead - I've found it a good libXML2 wrapper.

Comment: Oh and the C function you're after is xmlUnlinkNode, from here: http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html. It will probably be similar in libxml2.

Comment: I'm with Michael on lxml being awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, if the item you want to remove is an attribute `unsetProp` is the method of choice:

```
...
if node.hasProp('myAttributeName'):
   node.usetProp('myAttributeName')
```

> Does anyone have a decent documentation about this library?

[This libxml2 documentation](http://pyxmlsec.labs.libre-entreprise.org/docs/html/libxml2.xmlNode-class.html) helped me alot.